# Getting values in a file which is not present in another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, sh

I have two files

File1.txt:

```
docker/registry:2.4.2
docker/rethinkdb:latest
docker/swarm:1.0.0
```

File2.txt:

```
docker/registry:2.4.1
docker/rethinkdb:1.0.0
docker/swarm:1.0.0
```

The output should be:

```
docker/registry:2.4.2
docker/rethinkdb:latest
```

In other words, every line in File1 that doesn't exist in File2 should be part of the output.

I have tried doing the following but it is not working.

```
diff File1.txt File2.txt
```

Comment: You should filter out all lines that don't begin with "-". Pipe into `grep '^\-'` to get all lines needed, prepended with a minus sign. Then I think you could do `sed '/^-//'` to remove that beginning line. (this is until I find a better sed pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk you can do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `grep` for it:

```
$ grep -v -f file2.txt file1.txt
docker/registry:2.4.2
docker/rethinkdb:latest
```

If there are lots of rows in the files I'd probably use @user000001 solution.

Comment: Also note you might want to use `-F` to avoid treating each line in `file2.txt` as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

With `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)
```